# How to access my Google App Engine instance remotely

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am a beginner to Google Cloud. I have created a instance in APP ENGINE. I am able to access it from my local host. But I want to access it from my PHP application remotely. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you deploy an application on App Engine, it should be available to be accessed externally, by using the link generated when you run the following:

`gcloud app browse`

It will generated a link like this: `https://[YOUR_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com`

You can find more information on how to create a simple application that is accessible externally in the below tutorial.

- [Quickstart for PHP 7 in the App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/quickstart)